# Safely return multiple references to internal nodes, while still allowing mutation of other nodes

Tags: data-structures, rust, mutability, interior-mutability

Suppose, for example, I have a linked list which does not allow removal of nodes.

Would it be possible to return shared references to values which have already been inserted, while still allowing the relative order of the nodes to be changed, or new nodes inserted?

Even mutation through one of the nodes should be safe "on paper" as long as only one node is used to mutate the list at a time.  Is it possible to represent this in rust's ownership system?

I'm specifically interested in doing so without runtime overhead (potentially using unsafe in the implementation, but not in the interface).

EDIT: As requested, here is an example that gives the outline of what I am thinking of.

```
let list = MyLinkedList::<i32>::new()
let handle1 = list.insert(1); // Returns a handle to the inserted element.
let handle2 = list.insert(2);

let value1 : &i32 = handle1.get();
let value2 : &i32 = handle2.prev().get(); // Ok to have two immutable references to the same element.
list.insert(3); // Also ok to insert and swap nodes, while the references are held.
list.swap(handle1,handl2);
foo(value1,value2);

let exclusive_value: &mut i32 = handle1.get_mut(); // While this reference is held, no other handles can be used, but insertion and permutation are ok 
handle5 = list.insert(4);
list.swap(handle1, handle2);
```

In other words, the data contained inside the nodes of the list is treated as one resource that can be borrowed shared/mutably, and the links between the nodes are another resource that can be borrowed shared/mutably.

Comment: If you want to have multiple "cursors" at the same time, and each of them is supposed to be able to mutate the list, you need some kind of lock to prevent these mutations from happening simultaneously. In the single-threaded case, this could be achieved with `RefCell`, and in the multi-threaded case with `Mutex` or `RwLock`. In any case, there will be some runtime "overhead" if you want to ensure memory safety. (Overhead in quotes, since I'm not sure if something that is needed to achieve a goal can be called overhead.)

Comment: I read your description, and I am still not clear on what you actually want. That's why it's better to present a code sample, even if it's only "here's an interface and example of use".

Comment: (1) Are the nodes supposed to own the structure (shared) or are the nodes only references in the structure? (2) Are all nodes omnipotent, or could there be up to N "view" nodes but a single "modifier" node at any point in time?

Comment: (3) Does "allowing the relative order of the nodes to be changed" mean moving the nodes around, or just updating pointers that link them?

Comment: (4) Related to Peter's question: can you observe the neighbouring nodes from any node, or only observe the element held by the node.

Comment: @SvenMarnach The cursors are read-only unless one of them at a time is explicitly upgraded to read-write.  But the safety should be enforced by the liftimes of the access, not dynamically.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I expanded the original question with an example pseudocode. (1) The nodes are just the nodes of a linked list, owned by the list.  But the user of the API receives some "handle" to a specific node, through which they can access the node. (2) There could be N "handles" at a given time, and all N could be used to access the data immutably at a time, or one could be given exclusive mutable access at a time. (3) I mean to modify the links in the linked list, without touching the data.  (4) You can observe any node by iterating from any handle, and mutate any node through any handle.

Comment: @JeremySalwen: Regarding (1), is the handle received keeping the list alive (ie, can I allocate a list in a function, return a handle, and continue accessing the list from this handle) or does the handle only "borrow" from the list, and cannot outlive it?

Comment: @JeremySalwen: Your requirement of no run-time overhead is impossible to satisfy in the presence of `handle1.get_mut()`: it's a run-time condition whether a mutable borrow is ongoing on a given node's data (or a list).

Comment: @JeremySalwen: On the other hand, if you are open to some tweaks to the interface... but it'll look quite different.

Comment: @MatthieuM.  Regarding (1), my expectation was that the handle does not keep the list alive, and cannot outlive it.

Comment: I am definitely open to rewrite the interface, I was just trying to show conceptually what it would do.   I don't think that conceptually allowing mutable access requires a runtime check.  For example, the `handle1.get_mut()` could take a mutable reference to the list as an argument, which would allow us to certify at compile-time that it has exclusive access.

Comment: @JeremySalwen: I've prototyped an idea that should work; I've asked people to help reopen the question now that it's been clarified and I'll polish my answer in the mean time. Hint: access token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In other words, the data contained inside the nodes of the list is treated as one resource that can be borrowed shared/mutably, and the links between the nodes are another resource that can be borrowed shared/mutably.

The idea to deal with such spatial partitioning is to introduce a different "key" for each partition; it's easy since they are static. This has been dubbed the PassKey pattern.

In the absence of *brands*, it will still require a run-time check: verifying that the elements-key is tied to this specific list instance is mandatory for safety. This is, however, a read-only comparison that will always be `true`, so the performance is about as good as it gets as far as run-time checks go.

The idea, in a nutshell:

```
let (handles, elements) = list.keys();
let h0 = handles.create(4);
handles.swap(h0, h1);
let e = elements.get(h0);
```

In your usecase:

- It is always possible to change the links, so we will use internal mutability for this.
- The borrow-check on elements inside handles will be carried out by borrowing `elements`.

The full implementation can be found [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=449fbe1f711f7561dd6eeb6c491e3e4f). It heavily uses `unsafe`, and I make no promise that it is fully safe, however it is hopefully sufficient for a demonstration.

---

In this implementation, I have opted for dumb handles and implemented the operations on the key types themselves. This limited the number of types who needed to borrow from the main list, and simplified borrowing.

The core idea, then:

```
struct LinkedList<T> {
    head: *mut Node<T>,
    tail: *mut Node<T>
}

struct Handles<'a, T> {
    list: ptr::NonNull<LinkedList<T>>,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a mut LinkedList<T>>,
}

struct Elements<'a, T> {
    list: ptr::NonNull<LinkedList<T>>,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a mut LinkedList<T>>,
}
```

`LinkedList<T>` will act as the storage, however will implement only 3 operations:

- construction,
- destruction,
- handing out the keys.

The two keys `Handles` and `Elements` will both borrow the list mutably, guaranteeing that a single of (each of them) can exist simultaneously. Borrow-checking will prevent a new `Handles` or `Elements` from being created if any instance of them still lives for this list:

- `list`: grants access to the list storage; `Elements` will only use it for checking (necessary) run-time invariants and never dereference it.
- `_marker`: is the key to the borrow-checking actually guaranteeing exclusitivity.

Sounds cool so far? For completion, the last two structures then:

```
struct Handle<'a, T> {
    node: ptr::NonNull<Node<T>>,
    list: ptr::NonNull<LinkedList<T>>,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a LinkedList<T>>,
}

struct Node<T> {
    data: T,
    prev: *mut Node<T>,
    next: *mut Node<T>,
}
```

`Node` is the most obvious representation of a doubly-linked list ever, so we're doing something right. The `list` in `Handle<T>` is there for the exact same purpose as the one in `Elements`: verifying that both `Handle` and `Handles`/`Elements` are talking about the same instance of `list`. It's critical for `get_mut` to be safe, and otherwise helps avoiding bugs.

There's a subtle reason for `Handle<'a, T>` having a lifetime tying to the `LinkedList`. I was tempted to remove it, however this would allow creating a handle from a list, destroying the list, then recreating a list at the same address... and `handle.node` would now be dangling!

And with, we only need to implement the methods we need on `Handles` and `Elements`. A few samples:

```
impl<'a, T> Handles<'a, T> {
    pub fn push_front(&self, data: T) -> Handle<'a, T> {
        let list = unsafe { &mut *self.list.as_ptr() };

        let node = Box::into_raw(Box::new(Node { data, prev: ptr::null_mut(), next: list.head }));
        unsafe { &mut *node }.set_neighbours();

        list.head = node;

        if list.tail.is_null() {
            list.tail = node;
        }

        Handle {
            node: unsafe { ptr::NonNull::new_unchecked(node) },
            list: self.list, _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    pub fn prev(&self, handle: Handle<'a, T>) -> Option<Handle<'a, T>> {
        unsafe { handle.node.as_ref() }.prev().map(|node| Handle {
            node,
            list: self.list,
            _marker: PhantomData
        })
    }
}
```

And:

```
impl<'a, T> Elements<'a, T> {
    pub fn get<'b>(&'b self, handle: Handle<'a, T>) -> &'b T {
        assert_eq!(self.list, handle.list);

        let node = unsafe { &*handle.node.as_ptr() };
        &node.data
    }

    pub fn get_mut<'b>(&'b mut self, handle: Handle<'a, T>) -> &'b mut T {
        assert_eq!(self.list, handle.list);

        let node = unsafe { &mut *handle.node.as_ptr() };
        &mut node.data
    }
}
```

And this should be safe because:

- `Handles`, after creating a new handle, only ever accesses its links.
- `Elements` only ever returns references to `data`, and the links cannot be modified while it accesses them.

Example of usage:

```
fn main() {
    let mut linked_list = LinkedList::default();
    {
        let (handles, mut elements) = linked_list.access();
        let h0 = handles.push_front("Hello".to_string());

        assert!(handles.prev(h0).is_none());
        assert!(handles.next(h0).is_none());

        println!("{}", elements.get(h0));

        let h1 = {
            let first = elements.get_mut(h0);
            first.replace_range(.., "Hallo");

            let h1 = handles.push_front("World".to_string());
            assert!(handles.prev(h0).is_some());

            first.replace_range(.., "Goodbye");

            h1
        };

        println!("{} {}", elements.get(h0), elements.get(h1));

        handles.swap(h0, h1);

        println!("{} {}", elements.get(h0), elements.get(h1));
    }
    {
        let (handles, elements) = linked_list.access();

        let h0 = handles.front().unwrap();
        let h1 = handles.back().unwrap();
        let h2 = handles.push_back("And thanks for the fish!".to_string());

        println!("{} {}! {}", elements.get(h0), elements.get(h1), elements.get(h2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Very Cool!  I was unable to find anything on google about "brands" in this context.  I assume it's something like dependent types that refer to a specific instance of the list?

Comment: @JeremySalwen: Yes, the idea is that you link two variables together (for example, a list and an index guaranteed to be valid for it) at compile-time, and then you can write functions only accepting two variables with the same "brand". In Rust, lifetimes are very close, however the compiler is allowed to merge lifetime regions, so you cannot guarantee that two list instances will have distinct lifetimes and thus they cannot be used as brands. See https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2s2etw/leveraging_the_type_system_to_elide_bounds_checks/